# Inheritance and generic constraints

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, collections

I've been struggling with collections, generics and inheritance. Sorry, but I am not sure how to express my issue in proper way, but I'm sure this piece of code displays it enough.

```
public class A
{
    public IList<C> sequenceOfC;

    public A(IList<C> sequenceOfC)
    {
        this.sequenceOfC = sequenceOfC;
    }
}

public class B : A {
    public B(IList<D> sequanceOfC) : base(sequanceOfC) { } //compile time error 
    // Error 2  Argument 1: cannot convert from 
    // 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<ConsoleApplication.D>' 
    // to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<ConsoleApplication.C>'  
}

public class C { }

public class D : C { }
```

I cannot understand why I see this error. C D is inherited from C and everything should goes on, doesn't it?

Comment: The error is caused by the fact that `IList<T>` is invariant in `T`. For the assignment to work, it would have to be covariant. You'd have to use `IEnumerable<out T>` or [`IReadOnlyList<out T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh192385(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek: Since `C` is a class, the declaration of `IList<C>` is completely valid.

Comment: @Aschratt Good catch, I got confused by naming. Thanks for the correction, I removed it from the original comment, as far as I can tell strike-through markdown doesn't work in comments (?).

Comment: The compiler does not regard the lists as you or I would. You are thinking in terms of "a list of C" and "a list of D", with prior knowledge of the relationship between C and D, whereas the compiler sees only the closed type. Since typeof(IList<C>) != typeof(IList<D>) it cannot make the assignment.

Comment: @mungflesh it's pretty clear for me. But how it can be solved in situation I have?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `IList` is not covariant. Therefor the compiler cannot ensure that `D` can be converted into `C` in any case. The solution is to use `IEnumerable<C>` to initialize your list:

```
public class A
{
    public IList<C> sequanceOfC;

    public A(IEnumerable<C> sequanceOfC)
    {
        this.sequanceOfC = new List<C>(sequanceOfC);
    }
}

public class B : A 
{
    public B(IList<D> sequanceOfD) : base(sequanceOfD) { }  
}
```

Comment: But I thought that creating new sequence from existing it's not too good way of doing things. I mean it in sense of performance and optimization.  Isn't it?

Comment: Since you are using a list of classes there should be no huge performance impact. Class instances are reference types and therefor only the references get copied. That's actually quite fast. Linq's `ToList` does the same.

Comment: Okay, but if we thing of terms that IEnumerable<C> contains 1 000 000 items, then I create new List<C>. I am right than in time of creating of List<C> it will be reserved additional memory for 1 000 000 items?

Comment: No, just for 1.000.000 references, but not for the whole objects.

Comment: @frankie: As an alternative, you have to change your design. Use `IEnumerable<C>` for the `sequanceOfC`-member and simply copy the reference passed with the constructor. The rest depends on your design. For example this prevents you from easily adding elements. How you handle this situation hardly depends on your design.

Comment: thanks for explanation. I'll try to use co-variance arrays. It looks simpler at first look :)

Comment: @frankie: Whenever you want to use covariance, you will end up in what I descriped. An generic type parameter can only be covariant, if the generic interface only emits the type.

Answer (score 1):

If D inherits from C, and IList was covariant, you would be able to write:

```
public class E : C
{}

IList<D> source = new List<D>();
IList<C> target = source;
target.Add(new E());
```

which is obviously wrong as you would be adding an E to a list of D